# DJL is unable to find MXNet Engine, troubleshooting doesn't help me

Tags: java, maven, machine-learning, mxnet

I have now spent way too much time trying to resolve this on my own, but I seem unable to do this on my own. I wanted to try out [DJL](https://djl.ai/), looked at some examples and into the tutorial, and was very excited about it because it seems like a very modern, simple and versatile library. However, I ran into a problem I am unable to solve.

DJL proposes using its MXNet Engine as default engine in the tutorial. It is included via the maven dependency `ai.djl.mxnet:mxnet-engine:0.5.0`. When running the sample code from the tutorial, I encounter the following error message:

```
[main] WARN ai.djl.mxnet.engine.MxEngine - Failed to load MXNet native library
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'mxnet':
Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

Native library (win32-x86-64/mxnet.dll) not found in resource path (D:\dev\DJL Test\target\classes;D:\maven\repo\ai\djl\api\0.5.0\api-0.5.0.jar;D:\maven\repo\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.5\gson-2.8.5.jar;D:\maven\repo\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.20\commons-compress-1.20.jar;D:\maven\repo\ai\djl\basicdataset\0.5.0\basicdataset-0.5.0.jar;D:\maven\repo\ai\djl\model-zoo\0.5.0\model-zoo-0.5.0.jar;D:\maven\repo\ai\djl\mxnet\mxnet-engine\0.5.0\mxnet-engine-0.5.0.jar;D:\maven\repo\net\java\dev\jna\jna\5.3.0\jna-5.3.0.jar;D:\maven\repo\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.26\slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar;D:\maven\repo\org\slf4j\slf4j-simple\1.7.22\slf4j-simple-1.7.22.jar)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:302)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:455)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:192)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.load(Native.java:596)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.load(Native.java:570)
    at ai.djl.mxnet.jna.LibUtils.loadLibrary(LibUtils.java:68)
    at ai.djl.mxnet.jna.JnaUtils.<clinit>(JnaUtils.java:69)
    at ai.djl.mxnet.engine.MxEngine.newInstance(MxEngine.java:45)
    at ai.djl.mxnet.engine.MxEngineProvider.<clinit>(MxEngineProvider.java:21)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at ai.djl.engine.Engine.initEngine(Engine.java:45)
    at ai.djl.engine.Engine.<clinit>(Engine.java:40)
    at ai.djl.basicdataset.Mnist$Builder.<init>(Mnist.java:175)
    at ai.djl.basicdataset.Mnist.builder(Mnist.java:66)
    at Main.main(Main.java:28)
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:191)
        ... 20 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:204)
        ... 20 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:265)
        ... 20 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Native library (win32-x86-64/mxnet.dll) not found in resource path (D:\dev\DJL Test\target\classes;D:\maven\repo\ai\djl\api\0.5.0\api-0.5.0.jar;D:\maven\repo\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.5\gson-2.8.5.jar;D:\maven\repo\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.20\commons-compress-1.20.jar;D:\maven\repo\ai\djl\basicdataset\0.5.0\basicdataset-0.5.0.jar;D:\maven\repo\ai\djl\model-zoo\0.5.0\model-zoo-0.5.0.jar;D:\maven\repo\ai\djl\mxnet\mxnet-engine\0.5.0\mxnet-engine-0.5.0.jar;D:\maven\repo\net\java\dev\jna\jna\5.3.0\jna-5.3.0.jar;D:\maven\repo\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.26\slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar;D:\maven\repo\org\slf4j\slf4j-simple\1.7.22\slf4j-simple-1.7.22.jar)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.extractFromResourcePath(Native.java:1095)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:276)
        ... 20 more
Exception in thread "main" ai.djl.engine.EngineException: No deep learning engine found.
Please refer to https://github.com/awslabs/djl/blob/master/docs/development/troubleshooting.md for more details.
    at ai.djl.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:90)
    at ai.djl.basicdataset.Mnist$Builder.<init>(Mnist.java:175)
    at ai.djl.basicdataset.Mnist.builder(Mnist.java:66)
    at Main.main(Main.java:28)
```

(Please excuse the partially German error messages, I believe this occurs because MXNet is loaded via JNA and the native windows code uses a different locale. "Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden" means "the specified module was not found"). Now I *do* understand what this error is trying to tell me: DJL needs a deep learning engine and tries to load MXNet using JNA, but does not find the DLL. The error message provides a [link to the troubleshooting doc of DJL](https://github.com/awslabs/djl/blob/master/docs/development/troubleshooting.md) which should resolve my issues. But I couldn't figure it out even with this helper. Here are the steps I considered / tried:

Step 1: First of all, the troubleshooting tells me that MXNet is automatically downloaded / installed or whatever by DJL:

> By default, DJL is running on the MXNet engine. We use mxnet-mkl on CPU machines and mxnet-cu102mkl on GPU machines. mkl means Intel-MKLDNN is enabled. cu102 means Nvidia CUDA Toolkit version 10.2 is enabled.
>   You don't need to download and install MXNet separately. It's automatically done when you build the DJL project by running the ./gradlew build command.

Now I have never worked with gradle, I always use maven. I did not run the command because if I copy it into the terminal, it tells me that `.` is not a valid command. Is `./gradlew build` automatically executed when I build and run my project in IntelliJ?

Step 2: The troubleshooting file provides some details on the "No deep learning engine found" exception. But I've gone through all steps and now I am even more confused:

1. The dependency is in my `pom.xml` and is also loaded and visible in my external libraries
2. I cannot resolve the "IntelliJ issue" like the troubleshooting tells me. It provides two options. The first one tells me to navigate to `references-> Build Execution Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle` and change the option `Build and running using:` to `Gradle`. The problem is that this option does not show up, and I also didn't find it elsewhere. The second option is to "navigate to the MXNet engine resources folder using the project view". This confuses me, because where can I access the MXNet engine resources folder? At least I can tell it is not included in my maven-downloaded jar, should it be there?

Step 3: The troubleshooting doc tells me that I can choose to install MXNet externally, which turned out to be very complicated. But I did it, and I set the `MXNET_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable as specified. Still I get the same error.

So after all of this, I really don't know how to approach this problem, so I'm posting this question in order to possibly get some hints by people that are a little more proficient with this than me..

Thank you!

System and Applications:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Intel Core i5-7400 CPU, so I installed mkl and the mkl version of mxnet (mxnet-mkl)
- AMD Radeon R9 380 Series, so no CUDA mxnet for me, sadly
- mkl version 2020.1
- MXNet version 1.5.0
- Java 11 (OpenJDK 11)
- Maven 3.6.3
- DJL 0.5.0
- JNA 5.3.0 (required for DJL)
- Slf4J api 1.7.26 (required for DJL)
- Slf4J simple 1.7.22 (required for DJL)
- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2020.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include MXNet native dependency:
See example project's pom.xml file: https://github.com/awslabs/djl/blob/master/examples/pom.xml#L64-L72

For more detail about MXNet engine dependency, see: https://github.com/awslabs/djl/tree/master/mxnet/mxnet-engine#installation

For Windows, you can use: `gradlew build` in if you are using CMD, ./ is linux/mac convention, and should work if you are using gitbash on Windows.

Comment: Thank you so much, this actually solved my problem! But just because I am curious: Do you happen to know why my manual installation didn't work?

Comment: Are you installing mxnet by `pip install`? MXNet windows pip package is a old version. DJL 0.5.0 require MXNet 1.7.0, you can build from source on MXNet 1.7.x branch.

Comment: That could be it, indeed. Thanks! Although I will just use the native maven dependency from here on